# Phoenix: Cowboy errors in production

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

We recently deployed our phoenix app to production but at times, we intermittently have this error.

```
Error in process #PID<0.2328.0> on node :"competition@127.0.0.1" with exit value:
{:function_clause,
 [{:cowboy_protocol, :parse_method,
   ["",
    {:state, #Port<0.5743>, :ranch_tcp, [:cowboy_router, :cowboy_handler],
     false,
     [listener: Competition.Endpoint.HTTP,
      dispatch: [{:_, [],
        [{["socket", "websocket"], [], Phoenix.Endpoint.CowboyWebSocket,
          {Phoenix.Transports.WebSocket,
           {Competition.Endpoint, Competition.UserSocket, :websocket}}},
         {:_, [], Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.Handler, {Competition.Endpoint, []}}]}]],
```

Any one had any similar issues with cowboy?

Comment: Looks like https://github.com/ninenines/cowboy/issues/448.